# Обмен данными: клиент <-> сервер

Tags: java, android, сокет

Ввиду моего недостаточного опыта в программировании наткнулся на такие грабли:
Не могу наладить обмен данными между сервером и клиентским приложением на Android. На сервере стоит php сокет, при подключение по telnet все работает, при подключении выдает приветствие при вводе любого символа отвечает зеркально. Проблема в написании сокета на андроиде. Взял за основу его пример http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html?m=1 если его компилю то ни чего не происходит от сервера ответа нет. Доработал этот код немного под себя, убрал все лишнее но все тоже самое, ни ответа ни привета.

```java
package com.example.ildar.socket;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response;
    String serverText;

    TextView textResponse;
    Button buttonConnect;
    EditText editServerText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        textResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);
        editServerText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.serverText);

        dstAddress = "194.58.102.65";
        dstPort = 8888;

    }
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask();
                      serverText = editServerText.getText().toString();
                    myClientTask.execute();
                }

    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
                        new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }finally{
                if(socket != null){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            textResponse.setText(response);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/response"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Здесь должен быть ответ от сервера"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/serverText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ildar.socket">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Помогите хоть чем, хоть подсказкой куда копать, хоть носом ткните куда смотреть, с сокетами сегодня первый день работаю, голова еще не отошла после того как на сервере все собрал.

Comment: лучше такие вещи строить не на сокетах. Посмотрите на REST архитектуру.

Comment: Посмотрите в логе. Может быть срабатывает какой-нибудь exception?